# Javascript processing.js Why the image doesn't show up?

Tags: javascript, html, processing.js

I want to show a image on the canva, I use processing.js to do it, but it doesn't work.
The canva is working fine, but only the image doesn't show.
this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Processing.JS inside Webpages: Template</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p align="center">
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas> 
        </p>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script>
        var sketchProc = function(processingInstance) 
        {
            with (processingInstance) 
            {
        setup = function() 
        {
                   size(500, 400);
                   frameRate(30);
        };
        draw = function() 
        {
            background(255, 255, 255);
            image(loadImage('file:///C:/Users/acer/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/a.jpg'), 200, 200);
        };
            }
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);
    </script>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: you must start a server,javascript can't access local files

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor and an image from http://lorempixel.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not call `loadImage()` from the `draw()` function like that. That will cause you to load the image 60 times per second, which is very wasteful.

You should only call `loadImage()` **once** from the `setup()` function, and make sure you have a preload command.

But your problem is caused by the fact that JavaScript can't access local files like that. The `loadImage()` function needs a URL: either a full url to an image file, or a relative url pointing to an image in the same directory structure as the sketch. This is explained in [The Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/loadImage_/):

> **NOTE:** Some browers will not allow you to load images from file:// URIs. It is recommended that you use a webserver for your development and testing to avoid any problems with file:// URIs.

One more note: you need to get into the habit of checking [the JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools). I'd be willing to bet there are errors showing there that would have explained all of this to you.